# Using the video-card memory (ram) to store objects

Tags: python, video-card

Is it possible to store objects in the video-card memory instead of the ram? I have been using StringIO to store some objects in the RAM; would it be possible to allocate some of the video-card's memory for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without OS support. [PyOpenCL](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pyopencl) might have something that you can leverage for that.